# What are the pros / cons of switching from Puma to Unicorn in order to avoid threadsafe vulnerabilities?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thread-safety, multiprocessing, unicorn, puma

I've inherited a Rails application using Puma as a server. Puma was selected for its multi threading capabilities. Unfortunately, the application code is not thread safe and it has become hard to micro manage every new piece of code being added in let alone check whether updated gems continue to be threadsafe. I am thinking of moving to a Unicorn server for its multi processing capabilities, which will allow me to not worry about mutable state, code being threadsafe, etc. I know it will consume more memory but I am hearing that Unicorn also has issues with memory leaks and performance. Have you ever made the transition from Puma to Unicorn? Was it painful? How has unicorn performed? Has Unicorn proven to be scalable in a production environment?

Comment: fwiw https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/594

Comment: @BradWerth thanks, will keep that in mind. Hadn't heard of slow client attack DOS prior.

Comment: also, https://www.phusionpassenger.com/

Comment: @BradWerth very interesting! Looks like Phusion allows to choose from either multiprocessing or multi threading environments. Have you used it before?

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty versatile, we use it on over 100 production sites at work, and it's worked very well for us.

Comment: @BradWerth http://www.rubyraptor.org/how-we-made-raptor-up-to-4x-faster-than-unicorn-and-up-to-2x-faster-than-puma-torquebox/#slow_client_problem "Phusion Passenger 5 has a built-in buffering reverse proxy" to help combat the slow client attack. Will definitely have to keep checking Phusion out, looks promising!